# eCryptFS Confusion

Tags: encryption, home-directory, ecryptfs

I recently encrypted my home directory `chris` using ecryptfs. My understanding is that my encrypted files are stored in `/home/.ecryptfs/chris/.Private` and are mounted to `/home/chris` when I want to view them.

I just booted up my Windows partition to see if I could access still access my files and noticed that my home directory now contains:

```
chris/
chris.wyDpBnFC/
.ecryptfs
```

Now, my confusion is that the `chris.wyDpBnFC/` directory seems to be an unencrypted duplicate of my home directory that I can read? Why does this exist? Did ecryptfs create this automatically? Should I delete it, so that my files cannot be read unless when unencrypted with my key?

Comment: That is not normal behavior at all and I suggest you file a bug report against ecryptfs.

Comment: I seem to remember there being a rsync error when encrypting the directory for the first time. Maybe that was the cause of the strange behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Evidently, you ran [ecryptfs-migrate-home](http://manpg.es/ecryptfs-migrate-home), at the end of which, the following instructions were printed:

```
========================================================================
Some Important Notes!

 1. The file encryption appears to have completed successfully, however,
    chris MUST LOGIN IMMEDIATELY, _BEFORE_THE_NEXT_REBOOT_,
    TO COMPLETE THE MIGRATION!!!

 2. If chris can log in and read and write their files, then the migration is complete,
    and you should remove /home/chris.wyDpBnFC.
    Otherwise, restore /home/chris.wyDpBnFC back to .

 3. chris should also run 'ecryptfs-unwrap-passphrase' and record
    their randomly generated mount passphrase as soon as possible.

 4. To ensure the integrity of all encrypted data on this system, you
    should also encrypt swap space with 'ecryptfs-setup-swap'.
========================================================================
```

You need to go back and actually do Step (2) ;-)

*Full disclosure: I am the author and maintainer of [eCryptfs](http://ecryptfs.org).*

Comment: Apologies for that, I must've accidentally overlooked those instructions. Thanks for clearing this up.